# Custom PHP/SQL CMS htaccess rules

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made a custom PHP/Sql cms with a dynamic post template called blog-post.php

I am pulling in the content like so:

http://www.example.com/news/blog-post.php?slug=sample-slug-from-database

This allows me to pull in any number of posts using the same template, pulling info from the database.

I have spent 4 hours trying to achieve the following with htaccess ..

1. Force a trailing slash instead of .php extension
2. Force blog post urls to show as:

http://www.example.com/sample-slug-from-database/

instead of

http://www.example.com/news/blog-post.php?slug=sample-slug-from-database

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your preferred method of URL is to redirect everything, e.g. */sample-slug-from-database/*, I think it would be better to instead go with a less strict implementation, e.g. */news/sample-slug-from-database/*

Either way, here's the first implementation:

```
# URL
# INPUT http://www.example.com/random-slug/
# OUTPUT http://www.example.com/news/blog-post.php?slug=random-slug 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ news/blog-post.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And the second way:

```
# URL
# INPUT http://www.example.com/news/random-slug/
# OUTPUT http://www.example.com/news/blog-post.php?slug=random-slug

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news\/(.*?)(\/(.*?)*)$ /news/blog-post.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry Garry - none of those seem to work. I even tested with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood how they worked? Here's links to the both of them working in [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) ... 

[First One](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=128341fe-3c0a-55b5-8e3e-5716fbbf97cd) ... 

[Second One](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d9e25ed4-dc64-5aeb-a81e-ef826e6dc7a1)

Comment: Thanks Gary - absolute legend!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling - this is my final code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ blog-post.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```